# Extract IFC/RVT file information

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is there a way to extract information from a IFC/RVT on unix-based system?

I want to know how to trigger a translation job correctly for a given file without any additional information coming from a user.

I was given an IFC file, which translation was failing each time job was triggered. Based on the file description

`FILE_DESCRIPTION(('ViewDefinition [ReferenceView_V1.0]'),'2;1');`

it turned out that I had to use option `advanced.conversionMethod: modern` for that file.

I was looking for some sort of command line tool to use after user uploads a file.

Answer (score 0):

The closest we got as command line tool is this example which I am using everyday. But that will not necessarily address the IFC translation error as translation errors are not related with the way you call the API, but the IFC/Revit file content. If you still experience a translation error, there a re few things you can try:

- does your file loads in Revit on your desktop?
- do both modern and legacy mode fails?
- if this is a composite file, did you set the references appropriately?
- can you share the model with me for debugging? my email is cyrille at autodesk .com

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I forgot that when reading a file in binary mode, I have access to IFC file headers. Based on that I can decide how to trigger translation job.